# Updating a row according to a spatial intersection in SQL-SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, geospatial, spatial

So basically I have 2 tables;

1. `BORDERS` table includes `Id(int)` and `Geo(DbGeometry)` spatial column including polygons and multi polygons.
2. `OBJECTS` table includes `Id(int)`, `BorderId(int)` and `Point(DbGeometry)` spatial column including points.

I would like to fill `BorderId` column in `OBJECTS` table according to the intersection of `Point` column in it with `Geo` column in `BORDERS` table.

I would like to do it with SQL query. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use`STIntersects` to find the intersection. Your update query should look like following query.

```
UPDATE O
SET O.BorderId = B.Id
FROM BORDERS B INNER JOIN  OBJECTS O ON O.Point.STIntersects(B.Geo)=1
```

Above Query will not work properly when you have multiple intersections, to get the best intersection based on **Area covered**, you can use `.STArea()` to find the intersecting area  like following.

```
UPDATE O
SET O.BorderId =
  (
   SELECT TOP 1 B.Id FROM BORDERS B
   WHERE O.Point.STIntersects(B.Geo)=1
   ORDER BY O.Point.STIntersects(B.Geo).STArea() DESC
  )
FROM OBJECTS O
```

Above query will update the `BorderId`  with the `Border` table `Id` column having the maximum intersection area.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Spatial function  STIntercects for this.

```
UPDATE O
SET O.BorderId = B.Id
FROM BORDERS B
Inner join OBJECTS O O.Point.STIntersects(B.geo)=1
```